# Wordpress Astra custom template get form data

Tags: wordpress, forms, redirect

I want to make a wordpress page that handle the data from a form after redirected to it.

I can run custom php code after the redirect, but the ***$_POST*** variable is empty. How can I solve this?

Thank you for help!